# Autoload files when use require function

Tags: php, autoload

There's a magic function to autoload classes ([__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)), I want to know if there a way to load a file without a class.

Something like this:

```
require ('example_file'); // Trigger __autoloadfiles function

function __autoloadfiles($filename)
{
    $files = array(
        ROOT . DS . 'library' . DS . $filename. '.php',
        ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . $filename . '.php',
        ROOT . DS . 'application/otherfolder' . DS . $filename. '.php'
    );

    $file_exists = FALSE;

    foreach($files as $file) {
        if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
            require_once $file;
            $file_exists = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!$file_exists)
        die("File not found.");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define own function for requiring:

```
function require_file($file) {
    // your code
}
```

and then call it

```
require_file('file');
```

I guess that there is no way to overload `require` function.